# Monitor log file for a string, then create variable from same line to process said file

Tags: shell, awk, scripting, grep

I am trying to process audio logs to archive from Asterisk. Using Asterisk I have a log file (20190625.txt) that looks like this with 2 recordings:

```
20190625201018,RXKEY,1999
20190625201018,TXKEY,MAIN
20190625201018,RXUNKEY,1999
20190625201019,RXKEY,1999
20190625201021,RXUNKEY,1999
20190625201023,TXUNKEY,MAIN
20190625201115,RXKEY,1999
20190625201115,TXKEY,MAIN
20190625201115,RXUNKEY,1999
20190625201115,RXKEY,1999
20190625201127,RXUNKEY,1999
20190625201133,TXUNKEY,MAIN
```

I can not simply process the audio files and transcode when I run the script because the file appears as soon as the recording starts and shows up before it is done being written. However once the RXUNKEY, 1999 is logged the file is done being written. So I want to monitor the log file and when an RXUNKEY, 1999 is spotted I need the file's timestamp from the same line to be stored as a variable ($file).

I will then process the file using FFMPEG to convert $file.WAV to $file.MP3 storing it in a different directory. Then purging the original .WAV and deleting contents of the log file.

Inotifywait is not available on this system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
tail -f 20190625.txt | awk -F, '$2 == "RXUNKEY" && $3 == 1999 { print $1; fflush() }' |
while read file; do
  # Work with $file
done
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but that does nothing either in a bash script or straight from the cli.

Comment: @JaeNulton Eh, worked for my test. Maybe a buffering issue? Might have to add a `fflush()` to the awk bit.

Comment: (You'll also have ti kill it manually when done because of the `tail -f`)